# MySQL to Zend Framework (Derived Tables?)

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

Never done a derived query in Zend Framework, and I'll probably do it the long way around if I try. Just hoping some one may know a quicker and better way to code it and write it in Zend.

```
SELECT 
  compsite_id
  , compsite_name
  , compsite_url
  , AVG(comprate_vote) AS comprate_rating
FROM compsite 
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT 
             comprate_compsite_id
             , comprate_subcategory_id
             , comprate_vote 
           FROM comprate 
           WHERE comprate_subcategory_id = 1) AS rate
ON compsite_id = rate.comprate_compsite_id 
GROUP BY compsite_id, compsite_name, compsite_url
ORDER BY comprate_rating DESC
```

Comment: You want to use Zend_Db?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `adapter` and write the query in mysql syntax. For example if you are on model, get the adapter like this

```
 $adapter=$this->getAdapter();
```

Then use this adapter to write the query like this

```
 $adapter->query("SELECT compsite_id, compsite_name, compsite_url, AVG(comprate_vote) AS comprate_rating FROM compsite LEFT JOIN (SELECT comprate_compsite_id, comprate_subcategory_id, comprate_vote FROM comprate WHERE comprate_subcategory_id = 1) AS rate ON compsite_id = rate.comprate_compsite_id GROUP BY compsite_id, compsite_name, compsite_url ORDER BY comprate_rating DESC");
```

The other way to do the same

```
 $db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
 $db->query("your mysql query");
```

Comment: Object of class Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo could not be converted to string in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php on line 204

Comment: $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
  $select=$db->query("SELECT compsite_id, compsite_name, compsite_url, AVG(comprate_vote) AS comprate_rating FROM compsite LEFT JOIN (SELECT comprate_compsite_id, comprate_subcategory_id, comprate_vote FROM comprate WHERE comprate_subcategory_id = ".$comprate_subcategory_id.") AS rate ON compsite_id = rate.comprate_compsite_id GROUP BY compsite_id, compsite_name, compsite_url ORDER BY comprate_rating DESC");
  return $db->fetchAll($select);

Comment: @user611468 use this query in model as I mentioned earlier

Answer (score 0):

Not fluent in Zend, but you can make a view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW comprate1 as  
           SELECT 
             comprate_compsite_id
             , comprate_subcategory_id
             , comprate_vote 
           FROM comprate 
           WHERE comprate_subcategory_id = 1
```

Now you can rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT 
  compsite_id
  , compsite_name
  , compsite_url
  , AVG(comprate_vote) AS comprate_rating
FROM compsite 
LEFT JOIN comprate1 as rate ON compsite_id = rate.comprate_compsite_id 
GROUP BY compsite_id, compsite_name, compsite_url
ORDER BY comprate_rating DESC
```

This does not show a subselect and should not give you any troubles in Zend.

Comment: dude I think one of us hasn't understood the question. As for as I have understood, the questioner want to ask how to write query in zend? Is it? Or I am misunderstood the question?

Comment: @AwaisQarni, I translated the query to one without the subselect. If you elimiate that, it's just a straight join which is easy to use in Zend. So I'm giving the OP a workaround.